# How do you calculate tile notation order of growth?

Tags: algorithm, performance, runtime, time-complexity

I mostly understand big-O notation, as far as analyzing loops and whatnot to determine the efficiency of an algorithm like the various sorts, but my book's exercise says to "give the worst-case asymptotic running time in Big-O, and the worst case order of growth in tilde notation, as a function of N" for a given code fragment such as

```
int a = 1;
while(a<=N) {a*=2};
```

My guess is that the runtime would be O(log n) because a is being incremented exponentially and thus would be faster than linear O(n), but I'm not sure how this relates to order of growth or tilde notation

Answer (score 0):

In tilde notation, you should provide an expression f(N) (without dropping constants as in big-O) so that

RT(N) / f(N)   ----> 1
            as N--> infinity

where RT(N) is the run-time of the algorithm for big values of N.

In this example, f(N) = logN/log2.